# How to copy and paste multiple objects in same S3 location to generate ObjectCreated notifications?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I have already thousands of objects in my S3 bucket. I have written a lambda function now which process them and it gets triggered when a file gets dropped in that S3 bucket. I would like to copy some objects with matching pattern and drop them in the same bucket to trigger my lambda. Currently, I am following below method which takes a lot of time.

```
import boto3, botocore
s3_source = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_source = s3_source.Bucket('vistradata')

key_list = []
objs = list(bucket_source.objects.filter(Prefix='data/'))
for i in range(0, len(objs)):
     key_list.append(objs[i].key)

files = [i for i in key_list if 'mystring' in i]

def copy_data_from_s3(input_file):
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': 'bucket',
        'Key': input_file
     }
    s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'bucket', input_file)

for i in files:
    copy_data_from_s3(i)
```

Is there any better method using aws s3 sync or aws s3 cp? The examples I see online are copying data from one bucket to another and not in the same bucket. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could skip the S3 copying altogether.  Your existing `for i in range` loop can [invoke](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) your notification lambda directly for each file. This is what S3 does.  Your event payload would be a stripped-down version of the [S3 notification event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html) with only the `bucket`, `key` or whatever fields you need.

This will be faster and cheaper than copying S3 objects, but who cares? If this is a one-time operation, your or @Coin-Graham approach will also get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could run a command like this to force the notification to trigger.

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/* s3://mybucket/folder/
```

That would copy all the files inside the bucket to a new folder inside the bucket and trigger notifications for each.

You could also run that first with notifications disabled, then run it in reverse if need be.